# Passing state between screens in a Symbian/QML app

Tags: qt4, symbian, maemo, qml

I'm trying to use a `Loader` to load full screen components to changing screens in a Symbian/QML project. This doesn't feel like the correct way to do it, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

The example I'll use is a button on one screen which should open a full screen WebView (a.k.a ChildBrowser). I'd like to make the ChildBrowser a re-usable component, so need to pass the URL to it.

I've tried building a Javascript file with a `pragma library`:

```
.pragma library
var map = {};
function put(key, value) {
      map[key] = value;
}
function get(key) {
      return map[key];
}
```

For want of a better title, we call this `intent.js`.

The screen holding the button:

```
import "intent.js" as Intent

Button {
    onButtonClicked: {
        Intent.put("url", "http://example.com");
        console.log("Going to " + Intent.get("url"));
    }
}
```

Later on, in `ChildBrowser.qml`, I'm importing "intent.js" and then getting the Intent.get("url"). This is `undefined`.

My questions are:

- is using a `Loader` the intended way to build and transition between screens?
- how do you pass parameters between screens?
- how do you maintain state across the lifetime of the app? I'm especially interested in building controllers and models in Javascript.

I'm sure these are newbie questions, so a set of links to the relevant documentation is probably all that is needed; I *suspect not* however.

Answer (score 1):

Loader is a good way to avoid creating items until you need them.

Assuming ChildBrowser has a "url" property, you could do something like this:

```
Button {
    onButtonClicked: browser.load("http://example.com")
}
Loader {
    id: browser
    property string url
    function load(u) {
        url = u
        if (status == Loader.Null)
            source = "ChildBrowser.qml"
        else if (status == Loader.Ready)
            item.url = url
    }
    onLoaded: item.url = url
}
```

Adding a "url" property to your ChildBrowser is simply a matter of having a property on the root item, e.g.

```
Rectangle {
    property alias url: webview.url

    WebView {
        id: webview
    }
}
```

Comment: The loader still has to have some boiler plate at the call site. This gives me a couple of ideas, nevertheless. Thanks.

Comment: If you know that the loaded qml file won't be accessed over network you can take a shortcut here. If the qml file is coming from the local file system or a resource file, setting the Loader source is synchronous. With this assumption you can save the property on the loader, the onLoaded handler and the else if.